# Lawtex: Como faço para enviar um PDF da peça por email?

Tags: sendmail, lawtex

Estou com um template que envia um email no final, no extra, e estou tendo problemas para conseguir isso.

O código do envio de email é o:

`sendMail(<advogadoDoCaso.emailAdvResponsavel>, “Atenção, já está disponível a prévia com testemunhas do processo nº ” & <dadosDoProcesso.numerodoprocesso> & “. \b\b Acesse ” & documentInfo(<docInfo.link>, “pdf”) & ” e visualize o documento.”)`

A struct do docInfo é essa:

```
-<docInfo> : struct[DocumentInfo] {
    fields {
        +[link] : String
    }
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas, como chamar o documentInfo fora do sendEmail, mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, pois o email é enviado com o campo em branco, como se não existisse link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema no seu código é que você está usando `<docInfo.link>` na chamada da `DocumentInfo`.

Como ela espera uma struct e você passou só um campo de texto, ele retorna vazio, e por isso seu resultado é vazio.

Você tem dois jeitos de resolver isso:
1) usar `documentInfo(<docInfo>, “pdf”)` na chamada do email, e como sua struct só tem um campo, o `link`, ela só vai imprimir essa informação (se tivesse outros campos, iria imprimir um depois do outro, separados por vírgula)

2) antes do `sendMail`, chamar `documentInfo(<docInfo>, “pdf”)` e no envio do email só usar esse código: 
`sendMail(<advogadoDoCaso.emailAdvResponsavel>, “Atenção, já está disponível a prévia com testemunhas do processo nº ” & <dadosDoProcesso.numerodoprocesso> & “. \b\b Acesse ” & <docInfo.link> & ” e visualize o documento.”)`

Comment: Valeu @Luan, sua resposta é correta, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que ótimo que funcionou para você, @atGuz!

Answer (score 2):

Use `documentInfo` antes do `sendmail`. Ele serve para recuperar informações sobre um doc especifico, ou o documento corrente.

Comment: A lógica é essa mesmo, @GuilhermeUmemura!
A única coisa é que ele estava usando `<docInfo.link>` na chamada da `DocumentInfo`. 
Dá uma olhada na minha solução:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348337/132077